# error in install angular cli on ubuntu 14.06

Tags: angular, angular-cli, npm-install

I am trying to install angular command line interface on

ubantu 14.06
but when I run this command in terminal

I get this error:

i have node 4.2.6

and npm 3.5.2 install
proxy:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Inspiron-3521:~/Desktop/Python-2.7.14$ npm config get proxy
```

http://proxy/:port

error:

```
    ubuntu@ubuntu-Inspiron-3521:~/Desktop/Python-2.7.14$ npm install -g angular-cli
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy proxy:80
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Python-2.7.14/npm-debug.log
```

I also try this command

```
sudo npm -i --global install angular-cli
```

but it give same error
my npm-debug.log file is this

> > ```
> >   0 info it worked if it ends with ok
> > 1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs',
> > 1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
> > 1 verbose cli   'install',
> > 1 verbose cli   '-g',
> > 1 verbose cli   'angular-cli' ]
> > 2 info using npm@3.5.2
> > 3 info using node@v4.2.6
> > 4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
> > 5 silly install loadCurrentTree
> > 6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
> > 7 silly fetchPackageMetaData angular-cli
> > 8 silly fetchNamedPackageData angular-cli
> > 9 silly mapToRegistry name angular-cli
> > 10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
> > 11 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
> > 12 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/angular-cli
> > 13 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/angular-cli
> > 14 verbose request no auth needed
> > 15 info attempt registry request try #1 at 9:55:45 AM
> > 16 verbose request id 9ad243bd0c6a185a
> > 17 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular-cli
> > 18 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
> > ```
> >
> > proxy
> >     proxy:80
> >         19 info attempt registry request try #2 at 9:55:55 AM
> >         20 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular-cli
> >         21 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
> >     proxy
> >     proxy:80
> >         22 info attempt registry request try #3 at 9:56:55 AM
> >         23 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular-cli
> >         24 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy proxy:80
> >         24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.onError (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:174:17)
> >         24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:260:16)
> >         24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
> >         24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
> >         24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:258:9)
> >         24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
> >         24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
> >         24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at connectErrorNT (net.js:998:8)
> >         24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
> >         24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
> >         24 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for angular-cli { [Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
> >     proxy proxy:80] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
> >         25 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
> >         26 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
> >         27 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
> >         28 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
> >         29 silly install printInstalled
> >         30 verbose stack Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy proxy:80
> >         30 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.onError (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:174:17)
> >         30 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:260:16)
> >         30 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
> >         30 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
> >         30 verbose stack     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:258:9)
> >         30 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
> >         30 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
> >         30 verbose stack     at connectErrorNT (net.js:998:8)
> >         30 verbose stack     at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
> >         30 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
> >         31 verbose cwd /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Python-2.7.14
> >         32 error Linux 4.4.0-21-generic

Comment: Please check that proxy is set properly , you can install it normally. I don&#39;t think that proxy need to be set before local installation. I hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: Try running these two commands:                                                                                                    1. npm config set registry=http://registry.npmjs.org    
2. npm config set strict-ssl false

Comment: From the CLI docs: *Both the CLI and generated project have dependencies that require **Node 6.9.0** or higher, together with NPM 3 or higher.*